# Задача на ассемблере для К580

Tags: ассемблер

> Составить программу, которая анализирует третий разряд однобайтового кода, хранящегося в регистре B, и, если он равен 1, заносит в С код FF16, а в противном случае – код 0016.

Я пока не могу понять, что значит "третий разряд однобайтового кода " и как получить его

Comment: Это обидно - только появился вопрос, в котром ты вот прямо специалист-специалист, и этот вопрос задан так, что его сейчас закроют...

Comment: а как правильно задать?

Comment: @S.H. Вы сможете помочь?

Comment: ну этобуквально несколько окманд,причем они похожи на x86 -ассемблер. А вот как улучшить вопрос, просто чтобы его не закрыли: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @S.H. а что значит 3 разряд в однобайтовом коде?

Comment: @S.H.  и как этот разряд можно получить?

Comment: Думаю, это вот что: нулевой разряд - это самый младший, третий - это 4-й "справа" или "с младшей стороны".

Comment: получить так: записать в аккумулятор число 8 сделать AND с регистром B

Comment: @S.H. а можете,пожалуйста, дать пример числа, которое запишется в В?

Comment: "анализирует третий разряд однобайтового кода, хранящегося в регистре B" - у вас там по условию задачи - анализируемое число

Comment: @S.H. просто пример числа, которое может там быть

Comment: Ворос странный, но почему бы и нет... 0x2c - подходит для примера?

Comment: @S.H. это ноль в двоичной системе?

Comment: а разе это не 16 ричной системе хранится?

Comment: Хранится во внутреннем представлении процессора. А для людей записывается в разных системах. Начало 0x означает 16ричную систему, 0b - двоичную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу больше писать в комментариях, смотрите:

[Статья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%A0580%D0%92%D0%9C80%D0%90) о том, что представляет из себя процессор.

[Справочник по системе команд](https://demin.ws/projects/radio86/info/kr580/i8080.html), в котором перечислены регистры.

Алгоритм: взять число из регистра B и AND - нуть его с числом 8 - так удастстся выделить третий бит. Потом проверить флаг Z и в зависимости от этого сделать условный jmp либо на то место, где в C будет записано одно число, либо - в то место, где будет записан другое число.

Фактически, вам осталось сложить 2 и 2. Написать код на ассемблере, которогоу меня под рукой нет (последние 20-25 лет)

Comment: Теперь понялаа!!! и в комментариях тоже спасибо за ответ! Выражаю вам мою благодарность и признательность! пойду делать:)

Comment: Вы можете отметить вопрос как "решающий вашу проблему", поставив "зеленую галочку" рядом с моим ответом. Если, конечно, он действительно решает Вашу проблему. При этом рейтинг на этом сайте увеличивается не только у меня, но и у Вас :-)

Comment: ой, конечно! спасибо, что потратили на меня время

Comment: https://eliben.org/js8080/